# ImportError: No module named cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

When I run cqlsh from cassandra node it works properly but when i try to run same command from other server it give me following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dsecqlsh.py", line 95, in <module>
    import cqlsh # nopep8
ImportError: No module named cqlsh
```

I checked cqlsh  in same pathe and it is present.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: cqlsh shift with cassandra. make sure cqlsh present in the $PATH variable or the directory from where you running the command

Comment: In my case https://ibb.co/gePCk6

Comment: cqlsh is present in same directory and I also included in $PATH variable.

Comment: Try pip install cqlsh

Comment: Hey did it work for you? Shall I add it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right Python version installed. Is "other server" is part of the cluster as well? if not, Best way to do is to install cassandra on that node and using CQLSH command by supplying the host and port, that way you login into the Cassandra that you wanted.